# fe_sendauth: no password supplied error on PostgreSQL windows user

Tags: windows, postgresql, passwords

I was trying to login into psql from window command prompt and I got the error below

```
C:\Users\jjjjj>psql -U postgres

Password for user postgres:

psql: error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Please help!

Comment: I only get this if I use the `-w` option.  Otherwise, psql suppresses the error message and prompts for a password.  Maybe your psql is just a wrapper around the real psql.

Answer (score 1):

enable "passwordless" authentication by editing pg_hba.conf
replacing md5 or whatever other method by trust in both ipv4 & v6 sections

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Answer (score 0):

I located the file pg_hba.conf under C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data on Windows,
then I changed the md5 method to trust and restarted psql from cmd.It works for me.
For more info check
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-reset-password/